# java - How to retrieve anything inside method

Tags: java, methods, constructor, local-variables, bcel

From what i know, java cannot retrieve anything inside method. so i using option -g or -g:vars in javac.

for e.g :

```
class Test {
    int a=0;
    void method(boolean boo){
        String b;
        try
        {
            new Thread().sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test");
        BufferedImage image=ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\file.png"));
    }
}
```

So, i use BCEL to retrieve local variable.

```
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.*;
import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
class javap
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            JavaClass jc = Repository.lookupClass("test");
            ConstantPool constantPool = jc.getConstantPool();
            Method [] method=jc.getMethods();
            for (Method m : method) 
            {
                LocalVariableTable lvt=m.getLocalVariableTable();
                LocalVariable[] lv=lvt.getLocalVariableTable();
                for(LocalVariable l : lv)
                {   
                    System.out.println(l.getName()+" : "+l.getSignature());
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work if variable is not initialized like `String b`. Additionally I want to track constructor calls like `new Thread()` or `new File()` as well as invocations of static methods and inside intialize inside `JFileChooser` like `new File` and `JOptionPane` too. So I want to see in output `Thread`, `String b`, `JOptionPane`, `ImageIO`, and `File`.

What should I do, to make them are printed in my program?

Comment: "but it does't work if variable not initialized or constructor call not named in variable." - I can see that English isn't your first language, but I really don't understand what you are trying to say here. Can you reword this so it becomes clearer what you are saying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply cannot get the `b` variable, because java compilers (at least javac and ecj) do not put it into the generated class file at all: if variable is not assigned, no variable slot is allocated and it's not stored in the LocalVariableTable. You can create unused variable with longer name like `String blahblah;`, compile the class, open the compiled .class-file in text editor and search for `blahblah` string. You will not found it. So BCEL cannot help you to find the variable which is absent.

If you want to track new objects creation and static methods invocation, you can do it scanning the method bytecode. The easiest way to do it with BCEL is to utilize the `MethodGen` (even though you don't want to generate the new method). Here's the full code:

```
import org.apache.bcel.Constants;
import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantMethodref;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.LocalVariable;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.LocalVariableTable;
import org.apache.bcel.classfile.Method;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.ConstantPoolGen;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.INVOKESTATIC;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.InstructionHandle;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.MethodGen;
import org.apache.bcel.generic.NEW;

class javap
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            JavaClass jc = Repository.lookupClass("Test");
            ConstantPool constantPool = jc.getConstantPool();
            Method [] method=jc.getMethods();
            for (Method m : method) 
            {
                LocalVariableTable lvt=m.getLocalVariableTable();
                LocalVariable[] lv=lvt.getLocalVariableTable();
                for(LocalVariable l : lv)
                {   
                    System.out.println(l.getName()+" : "+l.getSignature());
                }
            }
            ConstantPoolGen cpg = new ConstantPoolGen(constantPool);
            for(Method m : method)
            {
                MethodGen mg = new MethodGen(m, m.getName(), cpg);
                for(InstructionHandle ih = mg.getInstructionList().getStart(); 
                        ih != null; ih = ih.getNext())
                {
                    if(ih.getInstruction() instanceof NEW) 
                    {
                        NEW newInst = ((NEW)ih.getInstruction());
                        String className = constantPool.getConstantString(
                            newInst.getIndex(), Constants.CONSTANT_Class);
                        System.out.println("Class instantiation: "+className);
                    }
                    if(ih.getInstruction() instanceof INVOKESTATIC) 
                    {
                        INVOKESTATIC newInst = ((INVOKESTATIC)ih.getInstruction());
                        String className = constantPool.getConstantString(
                                ((ConstantMethodref) constantPool
                                        .getConstant(newInst.getIndex()))
                                        .getClassIndex(),
                                Constants.CONSTANT_Class);
                        System.out.println("Static call: "+className);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```
this : LTest;
this : LTest;
boo : Z
Class instantiation: java/lang/Thread
Static call: java/lang/Thread
Static call: javax/swing/JOptionPane
Class instantiation: java/io/File
Static call: javax/imageio/ImageIO
```

Note that you have `java/lang/Thread` twice, because `new Thread()` is catched as object creation and `Thread.sleep()` is catched as static method invocation.

Comment: how about constructor call without named in variable ?

Comment: i'm sorry, i have no idea what is called this. but thanks for edit.

Comment: how about JOptionPane and ImageIO ?

Comment: Seems that you want to track static method calls as well. That's practically the same. You just need to check whether the instruction is `INVOKESTATIC` and extract class name from the MethodRef constant it refers.

Comment: can u make an example? i'm beginner using BCEL.

Comment: Edited the answer again.

Comment: thanks, i'm sorry I do not know much about the java structure.

Comment: to local variable how to remove L in front and ';' in the end ?

Comment: @newbie: sorry, that's not a stackoverflow format to place new questions in the comments. Use "Ask Question" button.